# Issues comparing the result of an HttResponse in android

Tags: android, android-asynctask, httpresponse

I'm having an issue trying to compare the result of an HttpResponse with an simple string.

What the code below do, is just get the response of an Http request. 
In this case the result of the request is a simple "ok", but when I try to compare it with another string the conditional doesn't work.

I'm able to show the response via toast message...to debug it and to confirm that it is what I'm expecting, but I don't know why the conditional is not working.

Thank's in advance.

`imports go here...`

public class HttpTest extends Activity {

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    DownloadWebPageTask task = new DownloadWebPageTask();
    task.execute(new String[] { "http://www.ecoeficiencia-ambiental.com/test/" });
}
private class DownloadWebPageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
        String response = "";
        for (String url : urls) {
            DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
            try {
                HttpResponse execute = client.execute(httpGet);
                InputStream content = execute.getEntity().getContent();
                BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(content));
                String s = "";
                while ((s = buffer.readLine()) != null) {
                    response += s;
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return response;
    }
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        if(result == "ok"){
            Toast.makeText(HttpTest.this, result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(HttpTest.this, "the conditional fails, the result is: "+result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}
```

}

Note: the manifest has the permission to use internet.
both the code and the URL are functional.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not use the equality operator to compare strings like that

Try

```
result.equals("ok");
```

Comment: Why I shouldn't?
is a common practice use conditional to compare strings.

Comment: Actually I tested your suggestion and it works, but Im still having the doubt why I shouldn't use "==" to compare strings.
I'm new in android, your help will be appreciated.

Comment: Doing a little research I found this:

Using == instead of equals() with Objects
When you want to compare objects, you need to know whether you should use == to see if they are the same object, or equals() to see if they may be a different object, but have the same value. This kind of error can be very hard to find.
--

Interesnting...I didn't know it. Thank you so much for your help. :)

Answer (score 0):

Oh, interesting! I guess that the string you get from reponse Entity including these things as well:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
```

Not just a single string 'ok' as you think. That's why comparison fails. 
You can confirm reponse by:

```
string response = EntityUtils.toString(execute.getEntity());
```

Have fun :)

Comment: I debugged the string and it only contains "ok", you can see it trough Log or toast messages. Thanks for your answer.